# Error 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a TodoApp and I can't delete a document from Cloud Firestore. Here's my actual code.

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _firestore
                .collection("todos")
                .where("author", isEqualTo: loggedInUser.uid)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapchot) {
              if (!snapchot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              }
              final todos = snapchot.data.docs;
              void deleteTask(snapchot,index) async{
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                myTransaction.delete(snapchot.data.documents[index]);
              });
              }
              List<TodoCard> todoWidgets = [];
              for (var todo in todos) {
                final todoTitle = todo.data()['title'];
                final todoType = todo.data()['type'];
                final todoDate = todo.data()['date'];
                final todoTime = todo.data()['time'];
                final todoCategory = todo.data()['category'];
                final todoWidget =
                    TodoCard(
                      todoTime, 
                      todoTitle, 
                      todoCategory, 
                      todoDate,
                      (){deleteTask(snapchot, todo);}
                       );
                todoWidgets.add(todoWidget);
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                  children: todoWidgets,
                ),
              );
            },
          )
```

I keep having this error:

```
'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

I know my way to delete is wrong so if you can explain why I'll be glad to know. Thanks guys!

Comment: Error in `deleteTask(snapchot, todo);` where `todo` is not an index, it is an object. You need to provide another way to delete object.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding `.reference` after index.

```
... await myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data.documents[index].reference)
```

Comment: Still the same error, I'll check another way to delete a doc but thank you